# Would encrypting a message twice with RSA with different keys be more secure that once?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

This was a practice problem for a class. The class is over now and I never solved it, so I thought I'd ask here.

Let's ignored the fact that adding extra security to single textbook RSA is unnecessary. As hilariously stated [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5383/101526):

> Think about it this way, if it is estimated to take 500 years for a prisoner to chew through the bars on [their] prison cell to escape, is the public any safer if we add a second set of bars so that it will take 1000 years to chew through the two sets before the prisoner can escape? Not really.

The proposed question:

> Does encrypting data twice with RSA and different keys increase security over encrypting data once with RSA?

Thinking about it now, I feel it would because you're introducing a second factorization problem that the adversary must compute.

Could someone please explain, mathematically, why I am correct/incorrect?

Note: For notation and algorithms, I am more familiar with that used in the original [paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf), particularly the use of [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), not [Carmichael's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_totient_function).

Comment: What does "increase security" mean to you? Specifically, does double-barring the prisoner's cell count as increased security to you? Either answer is fine, but it affects how I would respond to your query (if yes, then yes for the same reason; if no, then no for the same reason).

Comment: That is a great question. Unfortunately, I do not know what the professor meant. I guess we can assume "yes".

Comment: Assuming that the enemy must actually factor the public number (this has not been proved yet), the effort to break the code is of course larger, but only linear. Of course you could take another number for each letter of the message. Although at some point the message might be clear even if some letters are missing.

Comment: Isn't the second function not just called "Carmichael-function" ? I never heard this name.

Comment: Not clear question: 1) What do different keys mean ( each time the $p$ and $q$ are selected uniformly random or just new $d$ under the same modulus?) 2) Is this textbook RSA or do we have secure RSA paddings like RSA-OAEP or pkcs#1 v1.5 padding?